# iOS Sees PNG as a Video when saving to Photo Albums using UIDocumentInteractionController

Tags: ios, objective-c, png

All of my apps used to save directly to the Photos Album and that was it.  Time for me to get with the times and start using a UIDocumentInteractionController.

I found dozens of examples and tutorials.   Very few of them dealt with photos.  But they all pretty much said the same thing.

If I send a photo anywhere except the Photos Album, no errors occur and it works.  Saving to Photos Album, it generates the large message below but it still saves the image to the Photos Album.  For some reason, the word Video is in the message when trying to save a PNG.

Every aspect of the code works, except for this ugly error message that only appears when saving to the Photos Album.

My concern is Apple rejecting my apps due to that error message.

Has anyone ever dealt with this before?   Any help would be appreciated.

2018-10-27 19:50:40.085701-0400 TestImportandExport[28346:31506523] [Generic] **Video** /Users/xxxxxxxxxxxx/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/C1A267C3-5261-47BB-B4EF-92D93254D8A1/data/Containers/Data/Application/7FCD6086-B523-44AE-824E-D0E23886BF45/Documents/TestImportandExport_Sample_Image.png **cannot be saved to the photo library: Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11828 "Cannot Open" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x6000029525b0 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-12847 "(null)"}, NSLocalizedFailureReason=This media format is not supported.**, NSURL=file:///Users/xxxxxxxxxxxx/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/C1A267C3-5261-47BB-B4EF-92D93254D8A1/data/Containers/Data/Application/7FCD6086-B523-44AE-824E-D0E23886BF45/Documents/TestImportandExport_Sample_Image.png, NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot Open}

Here is the code:   ( I apologize for being an Objective-C dinosaur )

```
NSString *imagePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/TestImportandExport_Sample_Image.png",[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject]];

[[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:imagePath error:nil];

[UIImagePNGRepresentation(mainImage.image) writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES];

documentInteractionController = [[UIDocumentInteractionController alloc] init];

documentInteractionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:imagePath] ];

documentInteractionController.delegate = self;

documentInteractionController.name = @"TestImportandExport_Sample_Image.png";

[documentInteractionController presentOptionsMenuFromRect:sender.frame inView:self.view animated:NO];
```

Comment: Have you made any progress? I'm see the exact same error trying to save a PNG file to the photo album using a `UIActivityViewController`.

Comment: No, I found no solution.   It works on the Simulator and on hardware.  I submitted my app with this issue.  Apple approved it and it saves pics as expected.  No issues.